# Get user running HIVE job?

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I am running a HIVE job with my `UDF` extended class. I want to get the name of the user that submits my job, so i am using

```
System.getProperty("user.name");
```

to get the username but the problem is this is returning user **mapred**, and on the jobtracker the job is showing user name **hdfs**. I am currentely logged in as hdfs so the job is submitted by hdfs, so y is

```
  System.getProperty("user.name");
```

retuning an incorrect value:- **mapred**

Can anyone please tell me why this is happening and any alternate of getting the user name in the **evaluate** method of `UDF`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't have Kerberos authentication enabled, the system tasks will be ran as the same user the TaskTrackers are running as (in this case `mapred`, which is pretty common). This is because the TaskTrackers are running your process, not you.

Sorry, I can only answer half of your question. I don't know how to get the information from a Hive UDF.

---

Considering all of your UDF calls to the job have the same user... just "inject" it from outside of the script somewhere. For example, you can just add `whoami` to your invocation of the sql:

```
hive -e "select a.col, '`whoami`' from tab1 a"
```

Besides, just getting it once is probably better than connecting to the JobTracker every single time the UDF runs.

Comment: thanks for replying. here the issue will be:- say i am logged in as root user and i run the hive job, the job gets submitted via user hdfs on the job tracker. So whoami will return root, but i need the user being shown in the jobtraker

Answer (score 1):

I think you can look into this Job History API to get the username of the job submitter. I hope this may help.[Job History link](http://people.apache.org/~tomwhite/MAPREDUCE-1623/docs/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/jobhistory/JobHistory.html#getUserFromHistoryFilePath%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path%29)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the username as a parameter from outside. Then use it inside `UDF class`